# Is it possible to save result of "exec" into a text file python

Tags: python-3.x

**When I do this I receive an error :**

```
content = (open("to_be_intepreted.txt").read())
output = exec(content)
f = open("output.txt", "w")
f.write(output)
f.close()
```

Is there a way to achieve this?
The error I receive is:

Write() argument must be str, not None

Comment: What do you mean by "result"? `exec` always returns `None` and does not accept `return` statements. What information from the executed code are you trying to capture?

Comment: How would you interpret a file with python and return result on another file

Comment: Please be more specific by what you mean by "result."

Comment: product of the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [@ApproachingDarknessFish](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1530508/approachingdarknessfish) points out, [`exec`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec) executes the code and returns None.

Therefore, it's not possible to save the result of `exec` to a file. However, there are two options:

1. **Redirect stdout to the output file.**

   ```
   import sys
   import traceback

   # save a reference to the stdout
   stdout_temp = sys.stdout

   with open('to_be_interpreted.txt') as tbi, \
           open('output.txt', 'w') as out:
       # monkey-patch stdout (bad practice)
       sys.stdout = out
       try:
           # execute code using exec (bad practice)
           exec(tbi.read())
           # or rename to_be_interpreted.txt's extension to be .py and do
           # import to_be_interpreted
       except:
           # display any errors to the screen
           traceback.print_exc(file=stdout_temp)

       # flush stdout to write contents to file
       sys.stdout.flush()

       # reset stdout using reference
       sys.stdout = stdout_temp
   ```

   Monkey-patching a built-in module is a bad idea because it may have unintended consequences. However, you could keep the existing format of your `to_be_interpreted` file.

   In addition to security issues, consider replacing `exec` with `import to_be_interpreted` after changing the `to_be_interpreted` file's extension. Interpreting the code at runtime using `import` would let you know where errors are if any.
2. **Wrap the code to be interpreted inside a context.**

   After opening the file, print the content directly to the output file.

   ```
   with open('output.txt', 'w') as fp:
       # start to-be-interpreted code
       print('string to print to output', file=fp)
       # end to-be-interpreted code
   ```

   The advantage is minimal code needs to change in your current script and the file closes automatically.

   The disadvantage is references to stdout in `to_be_interpreted.txt` need to be replaced with the file.

Comment if you have any questions,

Clay

Answer (score 0):

You could run `exec` with new `globals` and `locals` dictionaries.

```
with open("to_be_intepreted.txt") as f:
    content = f.read()

loc, glob = {}, {}
exec(content, glob, loc)
```

The result should then be in one of the dictionaries, unless it has gone out of scope before `exec` ended.